# Install new programs onto USB stick

Tags: usb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Ubuntu to a USB key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key)

Hi I have made a working USB stick with Ubuntu 11.10 and I think it's excellent. I have installed some additional programs but they are gone whenever I next use the USB stick. How do I install new programs to the USB stick so that they stay there?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have installed it on a USB so it is *persistent*, or have you just got it as a *live USB*?

Comment: Hi, I followed the instructions on the Ubuntu website, under downloads to install to a USB stick using universal USB Installer.

Comment: I've had bad experiences with the Universal USB installer - I would just partition and install Ubuntu through the default live CD.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give additional space in your usb stick to store additional  data
this option is available in startup disk creator